# How are dementors born and propagated? Plus, can they die?

Tags: harry-potter

My question is very short;

I don't think it's handled in the *Harry Potter* books or movies, but yesterday, I was wonderring about dementors. How are they born? Do they procreate like humans/animals? Also, can they die, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in some detail over on Science Fiction and Fantasy in this [**Question and Answer**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8919/how-are-dementors-created-born).

> Dementors do not breed but rather grow like fungi under certain conditions. They multiply by feeding off human despair, unhappiness, hopelessness, and are akin to depression. They are pretty insidious creatures. Dementors have no soul themselves, thus their constant drive to suck the souls from others.
>
> According to J.K. Rowling:
>
> > "You cannot destroy Dementors, though you can limit their numbers if you eradicate the conditions in which they multiply, ie, despair and degradation."
>
> Dementors are JKR's representation of depression:
>
> > ***JKR*** (Rowling is asked about dementors being “a description of depression”): “Yes. That is exactly what they are. It was entirely conscious. And entirely from my own experience. Depression is the most unpleasant thing I have ever experienced. It is that absence of being able to envisage that you will ever be cheerful again. The absence of hope. That very deadened feeling, which is so very different from feeling sad. Sad hurts but it’s a healthy feeling. It’s a necessary thing to feel. Depression is very different. I think [dementors] are the scariest things I’ve written.”